# Simple weighted directed graph in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, graph

I have this simplistic Python class for representing directed weighted graphs (**digraphs** for short):

**Digraph.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

__author__ = 'Rodion "rodde" Efremov'


class Digraph:
    """This class implements a directed, weighted graph with nodes represented by integers. """

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes this digraph."""
        self.nodes = set()
        self.children = dict()
        self.parents = dict()
        self.edges = 0

    def add_node(self, node):
        """If 'node' is not already present in this digraph,
           adds it and prepares its adjacency lists for children and parents."""
        if node in self.nodes:
            return

        self.nodes.add(node)
        self.children[node] = dict()
        self.parents[node] = dict()

    def add_arc(self, tail, head, weight):
        """Creates a directed arc pointing from 'tail' to 'head' and assigns 'weight' as its weight."""
        if tail not in self.nodes:
            self.add_node(tail)

        if head not in self.nodes:
            self.add_node(head)

        self.children[tail][head] = weight
        self.parents[head][tail] = weight
        self.edges += 1

    def has_arc(self, tail, head):
        if tail not in self.nodes:
            return False

        if head not in self.nodes:
            return False

        return head in self.children[tail].keys()

    def get_arc_weight(self, tail, head):
        if tail not in self.nodes:
            raise Exception("The tail node is not present in this digraph.")

        if head not in self.nodes:
            raise Exception("The head node is not present in this digraph.")

        if head not in self.children[tail].keys():
            raise Exception("The edge (", tail, ", ", head, ") is not in this digraph.")

        return self.children[tail][head]

    def remove_arc(self, tail, head):
        """Removes the directed arc from 'tail' to 'head'."""
        if tail not in self.nodes:
            return

        if head not in self.nodes:
            return

        del self.children[tail][head]
        del self.parents[head][tail]
        self.edges -= 1

    def remove_node(self, node):
        """Removes the node from this digraph. Also, removes all arcs incident on the input node."""
        if node not in self.nodes:
            return

        self.edges -= len(self.children[node]) + len(self.parents[node])

        # Unlink children:
        for child in self.children[node]:
            del self.parents[child][node]

        # Unlink parents:
        for parent in self.parents[node]:
            del self.children[parent][node]

        del self.children[node]
        del self.parents [node]
        self.nodes.remove(node)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.nodes)

    def number_of_arcs(self):
        return self.edges

    def get_parents_of(self, node):
        """Returns all parents of 'node'."""
        if node not in self.nodes:
            return []

        return self.parents[node].keys()

    def get_children_of(self, node):
        """Returns all children of 'node'."""
        if node not in self.nodes:
            return []

        return self.children[node].keys()

    def clear(self):
        del self.nodes[:]
        self.children.clear()
        self.parents.clear()
        self.edges = 0


def test():
    digraph = Digraph()
    assert len(digraph) == 0

    for i in range(10):
        assert len(digraph) == i
        digraph.add_node(i)
        assert len(digraph) == i + 1

    digraph.remove_node(8)
    assert len(digraph) == 9
    digraph.remove_node(9)
    assert len(digraph) == 8
    assert digraph.number_of_arcs() == 0

    digraph.add_arc(8, 7, 20.0)
    assert digraph.has_arc(8, 7)
    assert 20.0 == digraph.get_arc_weight(8, 7)
    assert digraph.number_of_arcs() == 1

    digraph.add_arc(9, 8, 10.0)
    assert digraph.number_of_arcs() == 2
    assert digraph.get_arc_weight(9, 8) == 10.0
    assert digraph.has_arc(9, 8)
    assert not digraph.has_arc(8, 9)
    digraph.remove_node(8)
    assert not digraph.has_arc(9, 8)
    assert digraph.number_of_arcs() == 0

    digraph.remove_node(5)
    assert len(digraph) == 8

    digraph.add_arc(0, 3, 1.0)
    digraph.add_arc(1, 3, 2.0)
    digraph.add_arc(3, 6, 3.0)
    digraph.add_arc(3, 7, 4.0)

    assert digraph.number_of_arcs() == 4

    assert 0 in digraph.get_parents_of(3)
    assert 1 in digraph.get_parents_of(3)
    assert 6 in digraph.get_children_of(3)
    assert 7 in digraph.get_children_of(3)

    try:
        digraph.get_arc_weight(3, 100)
        assert False
    except Exception:
        pass

    try:
        digraph.get_arc_weight(100, 3)
        assert False
    except Exception:
        pass

    try:
        digraph.get_arc_weight(2, 3)
        assert False
    except Exception:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> def has_arc(self, tail, head):
>     if tail not in self.nodes:
>         return False
>
>     if head not in self.nodes:
>         return False
>
>     return head in self.children[tail].keys()
> ```

That last line has an unnecessary `.keys()`  The `__contains__` method on a dictionary searches the dictionaries keys.  Adding an extra `.keys()` to search a list (in Python2) or a set-like object (in Python3) is just extra memory waste.  Your whole function is just conditions, so you could easily fit it on one line:

```
def has_arc(self, tail, head):
    return tail in self.nodes and head in self.children[tail]
```

I took out the `head in self.nodes` part because if it is in `self.children[tail]`, that means that you added it as a node.

> ```
> raise Exception(...)
> ```

Raising `Exception` is rarely a good idea.  There is bound to be a more specific exception class that better fits the situation.  If there isn't, you should define your own.   Here, I would use `ValueError` or `KeyError`.  Here also you use `in ... .keys()`  That `.keys()` is still unnecessary.

> ```
> raise Exception("The edge (", tail, ", ", head, ") is not in this digraph.")
> ```

It's fairly hard to tell here what the format of your string is.  You should do something more like this:

```
raise ValueError("The edge ({}, {}) is not in this digraph.".format(tail, head)
```

> ```
> del self.parents [node]
> ```

I know it's nice to have your `node` words match up in the three lines, but adding an extra space before the bracket is against [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.  It says in the [Pet Peeves](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves) section:

> Yes: `dct['key'] = lst[index]`
>   No:  `dct ['key'] = lst [index]`

and, by the way:

> Yes:
>
> ```
> x = 1
> y = 2
> long_variable = 3
> ```
>
> No:
>
> ```
> x             = 1
> y             = 2
> long_variable = 3
> ```

Your `test()` function has some duplicate code.

> ```
> digraph.add_arc(0, 3, 1.0)
> digraph.add_arc(1, 3, 2.0)
> digraph.add_arc(3, 6, 3.0)
> digraph.add_arc(3, 7, 4.0)
> ```

could be changed to:

```
for arc in ((0, 3, 1.0), (1, 3, 2.0), (3, 6, 3.0), (3, 7, 4.0)):
    digraph.add_arc(*arc)
```

> ```
> assert 0 in digraph.get_parents_of(3)
> assert 1 in digraph.get_parents_of(3)
> assert 6 in digraph.get_children_of(3)
> assert 7 in digraph.get_children_of(3)
> ```

could be changed to:

```
parents = digraph.get_parents_of(3)
assert all(x in parents for x in (0, 1, 6, 7))
```

> ```
> try:
>     digraph.get_arc_weight(3, 100)
>     assert False
> except Exception:
>     pass
> ```

Your purpose?  Perhaps you are making sure that it throws an error?  That doesn't work.  `assert False` guarantees that there will be an error, but `pass` in your `except` block guarantees that you won't know about it.  You could do this:

```
try:
    digraph.get_arc_weight(3, 100)
except Exception:
    pass
else:
    assert False
```

That way there is an `AssertionError` if no exception was raised.  You have three of those blocks.  Use a loop:

```
for arc in ((3, 100), (100, 3), (2, 3)):
    try:
        digraph.get_arc_weight(*arc)
    except Exception:
        pass
    else:
        assert False
```