# Dijkstra's algorithm: traditional and bidirectional in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph, pathfinding

I have translated Dijkstra's algorithms (uni- and bidirectional variants) from Java to Python, eventually coming up with this:

**Dijkstra.py**

```
import heapq
from Digraph import Digraph
from random import choice
from random import uniform
from time import time

__author__ = 'Rodion "rodde" Efremov'


class HeapEntry:
    def __init__(self, node, priority):
        self.node = node
        self.priority = priority

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.priority < other.priority


def traceback_path(target, parents):
    path = []

    while target:
        path.append(target)
        target = parents[target]

    return list(reversed(path))


def bi_traceback_path(touch_node, parentsa, parentsb):
    path = traceback_path(touch_node, parentsa)
    touch_node = parentsb[touch_node]

    while touch_node:
        path.append(touch_node)
        touch_node = parentsb[touch_node]

    return path


def dijkstra(graph, source, target):
    open = [HeapEntry(source, 0.0)]
    closed = set()
    parents = dict()
    distance = dict()

    parents[source] = None
    distance[source] = 0.0

    while open:
        top_heap_entry = heapq.heappop(open)
        current = top_heap_entry.node

        if current == target:
            return traceback_path(target, parents)

        closed.add(current)

        for child in graph.get_children_of(current):
            if child in closed:
                continue

            tentative_cost = distance[current] + graph.get_arc_weight(current, child)

            if child not in distance.keys() or distance[child] > tentative_cost:
                distance[child] = tentative_cost
                parents[child] = current
                heap_entry = HeapEntry(child, tentative_cost)
                heapq.heappush(open, heap_entry)

    return []  # Target not reachable from source, return empty list.


def bidirectional_dijkstra(graph, source, target):
    opena = [HeapEntry(source, 0.0)]
    openb = [HeapEntry(target, 0.0)]
    closeda = set()
    closedb = set()
    parentsa = dict()
    parentsb = dict()
    distancea = dict()
    distanceb = dict()

    best_path_length = {'value': 1e9}
    touch_node = {'value': None}

    parentsa[source] = None
    parentsb[target] = None

    distancea[source] = 0.0
    distanceb[target] = 0.0

    def update_forward_frontier(node, node_score):
        if node in closedb:
            path_length = distanceb[node] + node_score

            if best_path_length['value'] > path_length:
                best_path_length['value'] = path_length
                touch_node['value'] = node

    def update_backward_frontier(node, node_score):
        if node in closeda:
            path_length = distancea[node] + node_score

            if best_path_length['value'] > path_length:
                best_path_length['value'] = path_length
                touch_node['value'] = node

    def expand_forward_frontier():
        current = heapq.heappop(opena).node
        closeda.add(current)

        for child in graph.get_children_of(current):
            if child in closeda:
                continue

            tentative_score = distancea[current] + graph.get_arc_weight(current, child)

            if child not in distancea.keys() or tentative_score < distancea[child]:
                distancea[child] = tentative_score
                parentsa[child] = current
                heapq.heappush(opena, HeapEntry(child, tentative_score))
                update_forward_frontier(child, tentative_score)

    def expand_backward_frontier():
        current = heapq.heappop(openb).node
        closedb.add(current)

        for parent in graph.get_parents_of(current):
            if parent in closedb:
                continue

            tentative_score = distanceb[current] + graph.get_arc_weight(parent, current)

            if parent not in distanceb.keys() or tentative_score < distanceb[parent]:
                distanceb[parent] = tentative_score
                parentsb[parent] = current
                heapq.heappush(openb, HeapEntry(parent, tentative_score))
                update_backward_frontier(parent, tentative_score)

    while opena and openb:
        tmp = distancea[opena[0].node] + distanceb[openb[0].node]

        if tmp >= best_path_length['value']:
            return bi_traceback_path(touch_node['value'], parentsa, parentsb)

        if len(opena) + len(closeda) < len(openb) + len(closedb):
            expand_forward_frontier()
        else:
            expand_backward_frontier()

    return []


def create_random_digraph(nodes, arcs, max_weight):
    graph = Digraph()
    node_list = []

    for node in range(nodes):
        graph.add_node(node)
        node_list.append(node)

    for _ in range(arcs):
        weight = uniform(0.0, max_weight)
        graph.add_arc(choice(node_list),
                      choice(node_list),
                      weight)

    return graph, node_list


def path_cost(graph, path):
    cost = 0.0

    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        tail = path[i]
        head = path[i + 1]

        if not graph.has_arc(tail, head):
            raise Exception("Not a path.")

        cost += graph.get_arc_weight(tail, head)

    return cost


def main():
    graph, node_list = create_random_digraph(1000000, 5000000, 10.0)
    source = choice(node_list)
    target = choice(node_list)
    del node_list[:]

    print("Source:", source)
    print("Target:", target)

    start_time = time()
    path1 = dijkstra(graph, source, target)
    end_time = time()

    print("Dijkstra's algorithm in", 1000.0 * (end_time - start_time), "milliseconds.")

    start_time = time()
    path2 = bidirectional_dijkstra(graph, source, target)
    end_time = time()

    print("Bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in", 1000.0 * (end_time - start_time), "milliseconds.")

    print("Paths are identical:", path1 == path2)

    print("Dijkstra path:")

    for node in path1:
        print(node)

    print("Path length:", path_cost(graph, path1))

    print("Bidirectional path:")

    for node in path2:
        print(node)

    print("Path length:", path_cost(graph, path2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can find the data structure for representing the graph [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124449/simple-weighted-directed-graph-in-python).

Performance figures can be as optimistic as these:

```
Dijkstra's algorithm in 37223.119020462036 milliseconds.
Bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in 93.41907501220703 milliseconds.
Paths are identical: True
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> from random import choice
> from random import uniform
> ```

If you are importing two things from the same module, put them on one line:

```
from random import choice, uniform
```

Your imports aren't in the order [defined](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> ```
> standard library imports
> related third party imports
> local application/library specific imports
> ```
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.
>
> Put any relevant `__all__` specification after the imports.

Your imports should look like this:

```
import heapq
from random import choice, uniform
from time import time

from Digraph import Digraph
```

First, the standard library imports `heapq`, `random`, and `time` are put in alphabetical order.  Then a blank line between that group and the local application specific import, `Digraph`.

> ```
> def traceback_path(target, parents):
>     path = []
>
>     while target:
>         path.append(target)
>         target = parents[target]
>
>     return list(reversed(path))
> ```

I would use `return path[::-1]`.  That way, you stay with a list instead of creating a `reversed` object and then converting that to a list.

> ```
> if child not in distance.keys() ...
> ```

The `__contains__` method of a dictionary already searches through the keys.  Using `.keys()` just puts extra information into memory that isn't needed.  Just do `if child not in distance ...`  You use that pattern in several places.

> ```
> best_path_length = {'value': 1e9}
> touch_node = {'value': None}
> ```

It looks like you have these as dictionaries so that you can change the values in sub-functions.  Since they appear to be related closely enough that they are always modified at the same time, I would suggest combining them:

```
info = {'length': 1e9, 'node': None}
```

`update_forward_frontier()` and `update_backward_frontier()` are almost identical.  I would suggest merging them:

```
def update_frontier(node, node_score, closed):
    if node in closed:
        ...
```

You could do something similar for the `expand_..._frontier()` functions.

> ```
> node_list = []
> ...
> node_list.append(node)
> ```

Your `Digraph` class already keeps track of a node list.  If you want to get a list from it, use `node_list = list(graph.nodes)` since the order doesn't appear to matter.

> ```
> raise Exception("Not a path.")
> ```

The exception class used should give some sort of indication of what type of error it is.  Using `Exception` doesn't do that.  You should either use a more specific standard exception class such as `ValueError` or define your own.

> ```
> print("Bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in", 1000.0 * (end_time - start_time), "milliseconds.")
> ```

That's 97 characters not including the indentation.  PEP 8 [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

I would make your code look more like this:

```
m_secs = 1000.0 * (end_time - start_time)
print("Bidirection Dijkstra's algorithm in {} milliseconds.".format(m_secs))
```

That's 76 characters without the indentation.  It's a little long, but it's a long string that you're printing.

> ```
> print("Paths are identical:", path1 == path2)
> ```

Won't the user find it a little string that it prints `Paths are identical: True` instead of `Paths are identical.`?  I might do something like this:

```
print("Paths are {}identical".format("not " * path1 != path2))
```

or:

```
print("Paths are {}identical".format("" if path1 == path2 else "not "))
```

Comment: `path.insert(0, target)` How Python lists are implemented? Array-based or linked list?

Comment: @coderodde: See [here](https://www.quora.com/How-are-Python-lists-implemented-internally).  They are array-based.

Comment: For that very reason `insert(0, target)` will degrade to \$\Theta(k^2)\$ where \$k\$ is the amount of nodes in the path.

Comment: @coderodde: I defer.  I will remove that in just a minute.  `return path[::-1]` is, I believe, what you were looking for.

Comment: Not that it makes much difference which one to use, since often \$k\$ is small.

Comment: *You could do something similar for the `expand…frontier()` functions* the difficulty there being the call to `graph.get_arc_weight()` needing the parameters in opposite order: lambda? At "every" call site of one of the "directional" functions? Leave the latter as wrappers?