# Traditional vs. bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in C

Tags: algorithm, c, graph, pathfinding, dijkstra

I have [this CLion project on GitHub](https://github.com/coderodde/BidirectionalDijkstra4Perl4). It constructs a directed, weighted graph consisting of 100 thousand nodes and 500 thousand directed arcs, picks two random nodes, and computes the shortest paths between the two using both versions of the Dijkstra's algorithm.

**Code**

**`algorithm.c:`**

```
#include "algorithm.h"
#include "dary_heap.h"
#include "distance_map.h"
#include "graph.h"
#include "parent_map.h"
#include "util.h"
#include "vertex_list.h"
#include "vertex_set.h"
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS) \
if (p_return_status) {                          \
    *p_return_status = RETURN_STATUS;           \
}

#define CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE   search_state_free(&search_state_)
#define CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2 search_state_2_free(&search_state_2_)

static const size_t INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY = 1024;
static const float LOAD_FACTOR = 1.3f;
static const size_t DARY_HEAP_DEGREE = 4;

typedef struct search_state {
    dary_heap*     p_open_forward;
    dary_heap*     p_open_backward;
    vertex_set*    p_closed_forward;
    vertex_set*    p_closed_backward;
    distance_map*  p_distance_forward;
    distance_map*  p_distance_backward;
    parent_map*    p_parent_forward;
    parent_map*    p_parent_backward;
} search_state;

static void search_state_init(search_state* p_state) {
    p_state->p_open_forward =
            dary_heap_alloc(
                    DARY_HEAP_DEGREE,
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_open_backward =
            dary_heap_alloc(
                    DARY_HEAP_DEGREE,
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_closed_forward =
            vertex_set_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_closed_backward =
            vertex_set_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_distance_forward =
            distance_map_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_distance_backward =
            distance_map_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_parent_forward =
            parent_map_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_parent_backward =
            parent_map_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);
}

static int search_state_ok(search_state* p_search_state) {
    return p_search_state->p_open_forward &&
           p_search_state->p_open_backward &&
           p_search_state->p_closed_forward &&
           p_search_state->p_closed_backward &&
           p_search_state->p_distance_forward &&
           p_search_state->p_distance_backward &&
           p_search_state->p_parent_forward &&
           p_search_state->p_parent_backward;
}

static void search_state_free(search_state* p_search_state) {
    if (p_search_state->p_open_forward) {
        dary_heap_free(p_search_state->p_open_forward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_open_backward) {
        dary_heap_free(p_search_state->p_open_backward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_closed_forward) {
        vertex_set_free(p_search_state->p_closed_forward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_closed_backward) {
        vertex_set_free(p_search_state->p_closed_backward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_distance_forward) {
        distance_map_free(p_search_state->p_distance_forward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_distance_backward) {
        distance_map_free(p_search_state->p_distance_backward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_parent_forward) {
        parent_map_free(p_search_state->p_parent_forward);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_parent_backward) {
        parent_map_free(p_search_state->p_parent_backward);
    }
}
typedef struct search_state_2 {
    dary_heap*     p_open;
    vertex_set*    p_closed;
    distance_map*  p_distance;
    parent_map*    p_parent;
} search_state_2;

static void search_state_2_init(search_state_2* p_state) {
    p_state->p_open =
            dary_heap_alloc(
                    DARY_HEAP_DEGREE,
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_closed =
            vertex_set_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_distance =
            distance_map_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);

    p_state->p_parent =
            parent_map_alloc(
                    INITIAL_MAP_CAPACITY,
                    LOAD_FACTOR);
}

static int search_state_2_ok(search_state_2* p_search_state) {
    return p_search_state->p_open &&
           p_search_state->p_closed &&
           p_search_state->p_distance &&
           p_search_state->p_parent;
}

void search_state_2_free(search_state_2* p_search_state) {
    if (p_search_state->p_open) {
        dary_heap_free(p_search_state->p_open);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_closed) {
        vertex_set_free(p_search_state->p_closed);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_distance) {
        distance_map_free(p_search_state->p_distance);
    }

    if (p_search_state->p_parent) {
        parent_map_free(p_search_state->p_parent);
    }
}

/* Constructs a shortest path after bidirectional search: */
static vertex_list* traceback_path(size_t touch_vertex_id,
                                   parent_map * parent_forward,
                                   parent_map * parent_backward) {

    vertex_list* path = vertex_list_alloc(100);
    int rs; /* result status */
    size_t vertex_id = touch_vertex_id;
    size_t previous_vertex_id =
            parent_map_get(parent_forward,
                           touch_vertex_id);

    do {
        rs = vertex_list_push_front(path, vertex_id);

        if (rs != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
            vertex_list_free(path);
            return NULL;
        }

        previous_vertex_id = vertex_id;
        vertex_id = parent_map_get(parent_forward, vertex_id);
    } while (vertex_id != previous_vertex_id);

    vertex_id = parent_map_get(parent_backward, touch_vertex_id);
    previous_vertex_id = touch_vertex_id;

    while (vertex_id != previous_vertex_id) {
        rs = vertex_list_push_back(path, vertex_id);

        if (rs != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
            vertex_list_free(path);
            return NULL;
        }

        previous_vertex_id = vertex_id;
        vertex_id = parent_map_get(parent_backward, vertex_id);
    }

    return path;
}

/* Runs the bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm: */
vertex_list* find_shortest_path(Graph * p_graph,
                                size_t source_vertex_id,
                                size_t target_vertex_id,
                                int* p_return_status) {

    search_state search_state_;
    double best_path_length = DBL_MAX;
    double temporary_path_length;
    double tentative_length;
    double weight;
    size_t* p_touch_vertex_id = NULL;
    int rs; /* return status */
    int updated;
    size_t current_vertex_id;
    size_t child_vertex_id;
    size_t parent_vertex_id;
    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex;

    vertex_list*    p_path;
    dary_heap*      p_open_forward;
    dary_heap*      p_open_backward;
    vertex_set*     p_closed_forward;
    vertex_set*     p_closed_backward;
    distance_map*   p_distance_forward;
    distance_map*   p_distance_backward;
    parent_map*     p_parent_forward;
    parent_map*     p_parent_backward;

    weight_map_iterator* p_weight_map_children_iterator;
    weight_map_iterator* p_weight_map_parents_iterator;

    /* Begin: routine checks. */
    if (!p_graph) {
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_GRAPH);
        return NULL;
    }

    rs = 0;

    if (!hasVertex(p_graph, source_vertex_id)) {
        rs |= RETURN_STATUS_NO_SOURCE_VERTEX;
    }

    if (!hasVertex(p_graph, target_vertex_id)) {
        rs |= RETURN_STATUS_NO_TARGET_VERTEX;
    }

    if (rs) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* End: routine checks. */

    /*
    Handle a case where the source and target vertices are the same.
    Otherwise, the algorithm may return a cycle containing the
    source/target vertex.
     */
    if (source_vertex_id == target_vertex_id) {
        p_path = vertex_list_alloc(1);

        if (p_path) {
            TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_OK);
        } else {
            TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
            return NULL;
        }

        if ((rs = vertex_list_push_back(p_path, source_vertex_id)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
            vertex_list_free(p_path);
            TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
            return NULL;
        }

        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_OK);
        return p_path;
    }

    /* Begin: create data structures. */
    search_state_init(&search_state_);

    if (!search_state_ok(&search_state_)) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    p_open_forward      = search_state_.p_open_forward;
    p_open_backward     = search_state_.p_open_backward;
    p_closed_forward    = search_state_.p_closed_forward;
    p_closed_backward   = search_state_.p_closed_backward;
    p_distance_forward  = search_state_.p_distance_forward;
    p_distance_backward = search_state_.p_distance_backward;
    p_parent_forward    = search_state_.p_parent_forward;
    p_parent_backward   = search_state_.p_parent_backward;

    /* Begin: initialize the state: */
    if (dary_heap_add(p_open_forward,
                      source_vertex_id,
                      0.0) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (dary_heap_add(p_open_backward,
                      target_vertex_id,
                      0.0) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (distance_map_put(p_distance_forward,
                         source_vertex_id,
                         0.0) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (distance_map_put(p_distance_backward,
                         target_vertex_id,
                         0.0) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (parent_map_put(p_parent_forward,
                       source_vertex_id,
                       source_vertex_id) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (parent_map_put(p_parent_backward,
                       target_vertex_id,
                       target_vertex_id) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* End: initialize the state. */

    /* Main loop: */
    while (dary_heap_size(p_open_forward) > 0 &&
           dary_heap_size(p_open_backward) > 0) {

        if (p_touch_vertex_id) {
            /* There is somewhere a vertex at which both the search
            frontiers are meeting: */
            temporary_path_length =
                    distance_map_get(
                            p_distance_forward,
                            dary_heap_min(p_open_forward))
                    +
                    distance_map_get(
                            p_distance_backward,
                            dary_heap_min(p_open_backward));

            if (temporary_path_length > best_path_length) {
                /* Once here, we have a shortest path passing through
                '*p_touch_vertex_id'.
                '*/
                p_path = traceback_path(*p_touch_vertex_id,
                                        p_parent_forward,
                                        p_parent_backward);

                if (p_path) {
                    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_OK);
                } else {
                    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
                }

                /* Clean up and return the path. The path may be NULL, which
                implies that there were no sufficient memory available for
                the path. */
                CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                return p_path;
            }
        }

        /* Choose the expansion direction. The smaller of the two search
        frontiers will be selected:
        */
        if (dary_heap_size(p_open_forward) +
            vertex_set_size(p_closed_forward)
            <=
            dary_heap_size(p_open_backward) +
            vertex_set_size(p_closed_backward)) {
            /* Once here, we expanding the forward search frontier generating
            the child vertices of the selected vertex: */

            current_vertex_id = dary_heap_extract_min(p_open_forward);

            /*  Mark that we know the shortest path to 'current_vertex_id': */
            if ((rs = vertex_set_add(p_closed_forward, current_vertex_id)) !=
                RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
                CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                return NULL;
            }

            p_graph_vertex =
                    graph_vertex_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes,
                                         current_vertex_id);

            p_weight_map_children_iterator =
                    weight_map_iterator_alloc(
                            p_graph_vertex->p_children);

            if (!p_weight_map_children_iterator) {
                CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);

                if (p_touch_vertex_id) {
                    free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                }

                return NULL;
            }

            /* Expand the 'current_vertex_id'. In other words,
            iterate over all child nodes of 'current_vertex_id': */
            while (weight_map_iterator_has_next(
                    p_weight_map_children_iterator)) {

                updated = 0;

                weight_map_iterator_visit(p_weight_map_children_iterator,
                                          &child_vertex_id,
                                          &weight);

                weight_map_iterator_next(p_weight_map_children_iterator);

                if (vertex_set_contains(p_closed_forward, child_vertex_id)) {
                    /* Once here, the shortest path to 'child_vertex_id' is already known.
                    Omit it: */
                    continue;
                }

                tentative_length = distance_map_get(p_distance_forward,
                                                    current_vertex_id) +
                                   weight;

                if (!distance_map_contains_vertex_id(p_distance_forward,
                                                     child_vertex_id)) {
                    /* Once here, we reached 'child_vertex_id' for the first time! */
                    /* Add to the forward priority queue: */
                    if ((rs = dary_heap_add(
                            p_open_forward,
                            child_vertex_id,
                            tentative_length)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);

                        if (p_touch_vertex_id) {
                            free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                        }

                        return NULL;
                    }

                    /* Mark that the distance and the parent maps should
                    be updated: */
                    updated = 1;
                }
                else if (distance_map_get(p_distance_forward, child_vertex_id) >
                         tentative_length) {
                    /* Once here, we are reaching the 'child_vertex_id' for not the first time,
                    byt we can lower its shortest path estimate. For that reason, we lower
                    that estimate: */
                    dary_heap_decrease_key(
                            p_open_forward,
                            child_vertex_id,
                            tentative_length);

                    /* Mark that the distance and the parent maps should
                    be updated: */
                    updated = 1;
                }

                if (updated) {
                    /* Once here, we need to update the shortest path estimate
                    and the parent of the 'child_vertex_id':
                    */
                    if ((rs = distance_map_put(
                            p_distance_forward,
                            child_vertex_id,
                            tentative_length)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                        free(NULL);
                        free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    if ((rs = parent_map_put(
                            p_parent_forward,
                            child_vertex_id,
                            current_vertex_id)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                        free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    /* Checks whether we can find the meeting vertex: */
                    if (vertex_set_contains(p_closed_backward,
                                            child_vertex_id)) {

                        temporary_path_length =
                                tentative_length +
                                distance_map_get(p_distance_backward,
                                                 child_vertex_id);

                        /* Can we improve the cost of a shortest path via the
                        meeting point?
                        */
                        if (best_path_length > temporary_path_length) {
                            best_path_length = temporary_path_length;

                            if (!p_touch_vertex_id) {
                                p_touch_vertex_id = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
                            }

                            *p_touch_vertex_id = child_vertex_id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            /* Once here, we expand the backward search frontier generating
            all the parents of the selected of the selected vertex:
            */
            current_vertex_id = dary_heap_extract_min(p_open_backward);
            vertex_set_add(p_closed_backward, current_vertex_id);

            p_graph_vertex =
                    graph_vertex_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes,
                                         current_vertex_id);

            p_weight_map_parents_iterator =
                    weight_map_iterator_alloc(
                            p_graph_vertex->p_parents);

            /* Expand the 'current_vertex_id' in backward direction generating
            its parents: */
            while (weight_map_iterator_has_next(
                    p_weight_map_parents_iterator)) {

                updated = 0;

                weight_map_iterator_visit(
                        p_weight_map_parents_iterator,
                        &parent_vertex_id,
                        &weight);

                weight_map_iterator_next(p_weight_map_parents_iterator);

                if (vertex_set_contains(p_closed_backward,
                                        parent_vertex_id)) {
                    /* Once here, the shortest distance to 'parent_vertex_id'
                    is already known. Omit it!*/
                    continue;
                }

                tentative_length = distance_map_get(p_distance_backward,
                                                    current_vertex_id)
                                   + weight;

                if (!distance_map_contains_vertex_id(p_distance_backward,
                                                     parent_vertex_id)) {
                    /* Once here, 'parent_vertex_id' is reached for the
                    first time. Add it to the backward search frontier: */
                    if ((rs = dary_heap_add(
                            p_open_backward,
                            parent_vertex_id,
                            tentative_length)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                        free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    updated = 1;
                }
                else if (distance_map_get(p_distance_backward,
                                          parent_vertex_id)
                         >
                         tentative_length) {
                    /* Once here, we can improve the distance to
                    'parent_vertex_id: */
                    dary_heap_decrease_key(
                            p_open_backward,
                            parent_vertex_id,
                            tentative_length);

                    updated = 1;
                }

                if (updated) {
                    /* Once here, we need to update the
                    auxiliary info: */
                    if ((rs = distance_map_put(
                            p_distance_backward,
                            parent_vertex_id,
                            tentative_length)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                        free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    if ((rs = parent_map_put(
                            p_parent_backward,
                            parent_vertex_id,
                            current_vertex_id)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
                        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                        free(p_touch_vertex_id);
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    if (vertex_set_contains(p_closed_forward,
                                            parent_vertex_id)) {
                        /* Once here, there is a meeting vertex: */
                        temporary_path_length =
                                tentative_length +
                                distance_map_get(p_distance_forward,
                                                 parent_vertex_id);

                        /* Possibly update the meeting vertex and the cost of the
                        path passing through it: */
                        if (best_path_length > temporary_path_length) {
                            best_path_length = temporary_path_length;

                            if (!p_touch_vertex_id) {
                                p_touch_vertex_id = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
                            }

                            *p_touch_vertex_id = parent_vertex_id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (p_touch_vertex_id) {
        free(p_touch_vertex_id);
    }

    /* Once here, there is no path from the source vertex to
    the target vertex: */
    CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE;
    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_PATH);
    return NULL;
}

/* Constructs the shortest path after unidirectional search: */
static vertex_list* traceback_path_2(size_t target_vertex_id,
                                     parent_map* parent) {

    vertex_list* path = vertex_list_alloc(100);
    int rs; /* result status */
    size_t vertex_id = target_vertex_id;
    size_t previous_vertex_id =
            parent_map_get(parent,
                           target_vertex_id);

    do {
        rs = vertex_list_push_front(path, vertex_id);

        if (rs != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
            vertex_list_free(path);
            return NULL;
        }

        previous_vertex_id = vertex_id;
        vertex_id = parent_map_get(parent, vertex_id);
    } while (vertex_id != previous_vertex_id);

    return path;
}

/* Runs the traditional (unidirectional) Dijkstra's algorithm: */
vertex_list* find_shortest_path_2(Graph* p_graph,
                                  size_t source_vertex_id,
                                  size_t target_vertex_id,
                                  int* p_return_status) {

    search_state_2 search_state_2_;
    size_t current_vertex_id;
    size_t child_vertex_id;
    double weight;
    double tentative_length;
    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex;
    int rs; /* return status */
    int updated;

    vertex_list*  p_path;
    dary_heap*    p_open;
    vertex_set*   p_closed;
    distance_map* p_distance;
    parent_map*   p_parent;

    weight_map_iterator* p_weight_map_children_iterator;

    /* Begin: routing checks. */
    if (!p_graph) {
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_GRAPH);
        return NULL;
    }

    rs = 0;

    if (!hasVertex(p_graph, source_vertex_id)) {
        rs |= RETURN_STATUS_NO_SOURCE_VERTEX;
    }

    if (!hasVertex(p_graph, target_vertex_id)) {
        rs |= RETURN_STATUS_NO_TARGET_VERTEX;
    }

    if (rs) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* End: routine checks. */

    search_state_2_init(&search_state_2_);

    if (!search_state_2_ok(&search_state_2_)) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
        return NULL;
    }

    p_open     = search_state_2_.p_open;
    p_closed   = search_state_2_.p_closed;
    p_distance = search_state_2_.p_distance;
    p_parent   = search_state_2_.p_parent;

    /* Begin: initialize the state: */
    if ((rs = dary_heap_add(p_open,
                            source_vertex_id,
                            0.0)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((rs = distance_map_put(p_distance,
                               source_vertex_id,
                               0.0)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((rs = parent_map_put(p_parent,
                             source_vertex_id,
                             source_vertex_id)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* End: intitialize the state. */

    /* Main loop: */
    while (dary_heap_size(p_open) > 0) {
        current_vertex_id = dary_heap_extract_min(p_open);

        if (current_vertex_id == target_vertex_id) {
            /* Once here, the search has reached the target vertex. */
            p_path = traceback_path_2(target_vertex_id, p_parent);

            CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;

            if (p_path) {
                TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_OK);
            }
            else {
                TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
            }

            return p_path;
        }

        if (vertex_set_contains(p_closed, current_vertex_id)) {
            /* Once here, the shortest path distance to 'current_vertex_id'
            is already known. Omit it.*/
            continue;
        }

        if ((rs = vertex_set_add(p_closed, current_vertex_id))
            != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
            /* Mark 'current_vertex_id' as settled. */
            CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
            TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
            return NULL;
        }

        p_graph_vertex =
                graph_vertex_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes,
                                     current_vertex_id);

        p_weight_map_children_iterator =
                weight_map_iterator_alloc(
                        p_graph_vertex->p_children);

        if (!p_weight_map_children_iterator) {
            CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
            TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY);
            return NULL;
        }

        /* Iterate over all child vertices of the 'current_vertex_id': */
        while (weight_map_iterator_has_next(
                p_weight_map_children_iterator)) {

            updated = FALSE;

            weight_map_iterator_visit(p_weight_map_children_iterator,
                                      &child_vertex_id,
                                      &weight);

            weight_map_iterator_next(p_weight_map_children_iterator);

            if (vertex_set_contains(p_closed, child_vertex_id)) {
                /* The shortest path distance to 'child_vertex_id' is already
                known. Omit it. */
                continue;
            }

            tentative_length = distance_map_get(p_distance,
                                                current_vertex_id) +
                               weight;

            if (!distance_map_contains_vertex_id(p_distance,
                                                 child_vertex_id)) {
                /* Once here, 'child_vertex_id' is reached for the first
                time. Add it to the search frontier: */
                updated = TRUE;

                if ((rs = dary_heap_add(
                        p_open,
                        child_vertex_id,
                        tentative_length))
                    != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                    CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
                    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                    return NULL;
                }
            } else if (distance_map_get(p_distance, child_vertex_id) >
                       tentative_length) {
                /* Once here, we can improve the shortest path estimate to
                'child_vertex_id':
                */
                updated = TRUE;

                dary_heap_decrease_key(
                        p_open,
                        child_vertex_id,
                        tentative_length);
            }

            if (updated) {
                /* Once here, we need to update the state for the
                'child_vertex_id':
                */
                if ((rs = distance_map_put(
                        p_distance,
                        child_vertex_id,
                        tentative_length))
                    != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {

                    CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
                    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                    return NULL;
                }

                if ((rs = parent_map_put(
                        p_parent,
                        child_vertex_id,
                        current_vertex_id))
                    != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
                    CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
                    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Once here, there is no path from the source vertex
    to the target vertex:
    */
    CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
    TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(RETURN_STATUS_NO_PATH);
    return NULL;
}
```

**Critique request**

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind. Also, I ran my program against valgrind: no memory leaks detected, so I suggest you don't waste your time searching for any.

**Outro**

If you run the entire demo program, you will likely observe that the bidirectional algorithms is faster than the traditional one by two orders of magnitude. Typical output follows:

```
Seed = 1648197281

Built the graph in 1768 milliseconds.
Source node: 16222
Target node: 79241
--- Bidirectional Dijkstra:
16222
57355
99046
17632
57708
23745
62656
12104
15177
432
72091
67852
42272
67600
91412
43363
43827
56094
90931
79241
Path length: 28.349254
Duration: 4 milliseconds.
Result status: 0

--- Original Dijkstra:
16222
57355
99046
17632
57708
23745
62656
12104
15177
432
72091
67852
42272
67600
91412
43363
43827
56094
90931
79241
Path length: 28.349254
Duration: 210 milliseconds.
Result status: 0
Algorithms agree: 1
Exiting...
```

Comment: ([aged Python rendition](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124460))

Comment: Code looks manually formatted.  Or did you you use an auto format?

Comment: Was it intentional for the macro `TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS` to have `}                                               \\`?

Comment: The scarcity of comments makes the code excessively challenging to review.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Point. I will add the comments today.

Comment: (Um - there's a `CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2` before `search_state_2_init(&search_state_2_)`)

Comment: Any particular C standard you are targeting? X3.159-1989?

Comment: @greybeard ANSI C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main issue with this C89 rendition is readability.
I revisited your [2016 Python rendition](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124460) which reads inconspicuous.
I think the problem here is the bulk, the verbosity.
(The code layout being lavish with vertical space compounds to the issue.)

Your library style ADT implementations have names that make collisions unlikely.
I suggest to provide short names that allow for fluent reading -
either optional generic ones in the ADT's header,
or names tailored to the context (maybe both?)

There is a striking amount of repetitive handling of cleanup and *error returns*.
The bulk could be reduced by just "jamming" *same* statements controlled by successive conditions:

```
    if ((rs = dary_heap_add(p_open, source_vertex_id,
                            0.0)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK
      ||(rs = distance_map_put(p_distance, source_vertex_id,
                               0.0)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK
      ||(rs = parent_map_put(p_parent, source_vertex_id,
                             source_vertex_id)) != RETURN_STATUS_OK) {
        CLEAN_SEARCH_STATE_2;
        TRY_REPORT_RETURN_STATUS(rs);
        return NULL;
    }
```

- I'd introduce a macro `return_ERROR(status)`
  (Similar to `search_state_ok()` handling? Naa…)
Rather than cleaning up at every error return (and conditionally exporting a status), you could create a wrapper `run_shortest_path(graph, source, target, pstatus, find_path, state_size, init, cleanup)`:

```
vertex_list *
run_shortest_path(Graph const * const p_graph,
        vertex_id source,
        vertex_id target, 
        int* pstatus,
        vertex_list *(*find_path)(), 
        size_t state_size, int (*init)(), /* boolean: successful - state, rather? */
        void (*cleanup)()) 
/** Run find_path: allocate&initialise state, call find_path, clean up */
{
    vertex_list *path = NULL;
    int return_status = RETURN_STATUS_NO_MEMORY;  /* ? allows just "return NULL" */
    void *state = NULL;  /* variable length arrays non-standard before C99 */
    if (0 == state_size || NULL != (state = calloc(1, state_size))) {
        if (0 == state_size || NULL == init
            || init(state))
            path = find_path(p_graph, source, target,
                             &return_status, &state);
        if (NULL != cleanup)
            cleanup(state);
    }
    if (NULL != pstatus)
        *pstatus = return_status;
    return path;
}
```

(needs amends in `find_path()` (`search_state_.…`→`state->…`).)

There is a troubling amount of duplication "between directions".
Thinking of `search_state` as a `search_state_2[2]`:

```
static void
init(void* outer) {
    search_state_2 *state = (search_state_2 *)outer;
    return search_state_2_init(state)
        && search_state_2_init(state + 1);
}
/* Possible, but not advisable in find_shortest_path():
    search_state_2 *state = (search_state_2 *)outer;
    p_open_forward      = search_state->p_open;
    p_closed_forward    = search_state->p_closed;
    p_distance_forward  = search_state->p_distance;
    p_parent_forward    = search_state->p_parent;
    state += 1;
    p_open_backward     = search_state->p_open;
    p_closed_backward   = search_state->p_closed;
    … */
```

---

The naming makes me wonder about the Java rendition I assume original - is that well-known/readily accessible?
I might prefer *waiting* over open, *finished* over closed, (out/in)neighbours over parents/children.

While I see one merit to it, I didn't expect choice of vertex to handle "by shorter frontier".
I guess you can construct a graph to make any scheme look bad -
How about, one from source, one from target, *k* from shorter?

I don't buy the choice of data structures to map from ID to vertex and from vertex to neighbours:
I'd expect the ID space to be densely populated from 0,
and the number of neighbours to be smallish:
arrays for both! (Rather than, seeing `id` in vertex, replacing ID with pointers on construction)

I would have considered C89 an odd choice in 2016:
What's the story behind *Dijkstra for Perl 4*?

Comment: (Seeing *Dijkstra for Perl 2* (&3) on GitHub, *Perl 4* in all likelihood doesn't refer to a language version.)

Comment: (`"by shorter frontier"` Did I review a comment? `heap_size(open)` is closest to *frontier* in my eyes, and the sum with `set_size(closed)` more like *total discovered*.)